# Track API requests to each pod on my kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, metrics

I am trying to track all API requests to my kubernetes cluster running on some ec2 instances. How do I go about doing this?

I am basically trying to check which IP the request is sent from, any data sent and any other discerning information.

I tried using prometheus but have not had any luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [Auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/) on your cluster. For specific resource, use `resourceNames` in the audit policy to specify the resource name.

Comment: Can auditing be used to track api requests to specific applications. I have some applications running and I want to know what request goes where.

Comment: You can specify resource name using `resourceNames` in the policy.

Comment: Could you please give a small example, i am new to using k8s and the documentation page isn't of much help. Thank you

Comment: Try [here](https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/how-to-enable-kubernetes-auditing-feature-in-minikube-running-locally-e45f0d68ff82).

Answer (score 1):

You can setup auditing in your Kubernetes Cluster.
Refer to this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).